# 'The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel' after SSL setup

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, httpwebrequest

In a web service running on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5. I have set up an api call with the following code

```
// ignore untrusted ssl connection
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

// create web request
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(REMOTE_URL);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";                        
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(REQUEST_STRING);
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Close();
}           

// fetch response
httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
statusCode = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode;
```

It was working fine. After that I tried to install the SSL certificate in IIS server, get a new HTTPs web service running, and put the module with above code into the web service, the nightmare began and the following line started returning **The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel**.

```
httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

I have tried to roll back by using the old web service with installed certificate removed but no luck.

Also tried the following methods but all failed.

1) Adding

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

2) Modify ApplicationPool Identitiy and set Load User Profile to True

3) Add the certificate in Personal Certificate and Intermediate Certifcation Authorities Certificate through Certificate MMC

A bit struggling so any hints and ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you installed the certificate on the server you're trying to contact, or the one running the code above? You might get some useful information from [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which will let you see exactly what's going through the network (including what certificates/protocols are being used).

Comment: @Rob I was installing the cert for my server with above code running, nothing to do with the remote one I was calling. Thanks for the link I'll give it a try.